# two war modules integration

Tags: java, spring, maven

i have made two maven  projects : the first is a generic authentification module with spring security with this structure :

```
ear 
|...warModule
|    |...ejbModule
|...ejbModule
```

the second is a CRM have this structure

```
ear
|...warModule
    |...ejbModule
|...ejbModule
```

now i want to integrate both so i can manage the CRM security with my authentification project (control url access ,permissions ...)is there a way to do that ?

Comment: no clear for me; which is the difrrence between the tow projects?

Comment: there is no difference between their structures .... what i posted is general structures but i just want to know how they can communicate with each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is that, you declare first project as dependency in your second project POM file.

For detail you can check: [Maven Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Sample code to add Dependencies:

```
 <project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-a</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact 1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-a</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact 2</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>`
```

Second way and I would suggest to use Overlay approach to integrate multiple modules and another benefit to use overlay is can share common resources across multiple applications.

Answer (score 0):

You have just to add a dependency declaration in one *pom.xml* file which point to the other artifact. For example lets say the downside lines are your CRM pom file:

```xml
<project>
  <groupId>crm.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>crm-artifact-id</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>authentication.group.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>authentication-artifact-id</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

It is just a sample and should be updated following your projects/modules group/artifact IDs.